# how to disable next-auth "refetchOnWindowFocus" on a single page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am working with live chart and data in a couple of pages of my app ,The problem is anytime i switch from/to the pages that are feeded with live data , their state get updated by "refetchOnWindowFocus" and causes a flicker in chart,
Is there a way i can prevent a single page from updating the session when it loses/gains focus, while keeping the "refetchOnWindowFocus" enabled globally?
what hooks are called when tab is switched?